# PHP | MailerSend API Unresponsive/Not Working

Tags: php, rest, email

I'm trying to integrate the MailerSend API to my PHP system but when I call the API it does not send an e-mail and I do not get any error returned from the API.

I have installed the required libraries using Composer. The script to make a call to the API is available on the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/mailersend/mailersend-php).

Can someone advise me on what to do? Did I make an error in my programming?

Thanks a lot for your time.

```
<?php
// INCLUDING MAILERSEND LIBRARIES
use MailerSend\MailerSend;
use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\Recipient;
use MailerSend\Helpers\Builder\EmailParams;

//include('../conn.php'); // DATABASE CONNECTION FILE
include('settings.php'); // THIS IS WHERE ALL MAILING SETTINGS ARE SAVED IN VARIABLES

$mailersend = new MailerSend(['api_key' => $mailing_api]); // FETCHED FROM THE SETTINGS.PHP FILE

$recipients = [
    new Recipient('recipient@email.com', 'recipient_name'), // TEXT IS GOING TO BE REPLACED WITH $ VARIABLE
];

$emailParams = (new EmailParams())
    ->setFrom($mailing_sending_domain) // FETCHED FROM THE SETTINGS.PHP FILE
    ->setFromName($mailing_from_name_users) // FETCHED FROM THE SETTINGS.PHP FILE
    ->setRecipients($recipients)
    ->setSubject('Test Message')
    ->setHtml('<p>Test message</p>')
    ->setText('');

$mailersend->email->send($emailParams);
```

Comment: 1) turn on errorlogging, and check the logs, 2) check the docs of MailerSend for extra debugging options (high 'verbose' level or something like that)

Comment: Try to set the text value, it is required, as per docs https://developers.mailersend.com/api/v1/email.html#send-an-email